# PHP - Wrong date format

Tags: php, date, soap

I am trying to communicate with a SOAP server and I am sending data to server however it is rejecting the date format that I am using. I have literally tried everything for the last two days and as far as I am seeing the format is correct. This is the code I am using to generate the date. I have read over similar questions but I cant seem to find an answer in any of them.

```
$_dateTo=date('Y-m-d');

Output 
2015-01-28
```

This is the error that it generates.

```
SoapFault Object ( [message:protected] => Date to is in wrong format, should be: 'YYYY-MM-DD' [string:Exception:private]
```

This is the XML

```
<message name="webrequestRequest">
<part name="studentId" type="xsd:integer"/>
<part name="type" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="dateFrom" type="xsd:date"/>
<part name="dateTo" type="xsd:date"/>
<part name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="extraField1" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="extraField2" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="extraField3" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
```

Comment: Give us more information. maybe some xml?

Comment: I think the error is not in dateFrom, but in dateTo. What the value you are using in dateTo?

Comment: Oh sorry that should actually read $_dateTo. I made the edit. The same error is returned with the dateFrom as well. It doesn't accept any of my date formats. @SandroEric

Comment: I don't think this is going to fix it but have you tried double-quotes? (Always worth a trie :D)

Comment: And, one more thing. Is that the xml you send using SOAP? Because there are no values in it. If it was just meant as example, can you show us the xml being submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and see if it gives you any errors

```
$dateFrom = new DateTime();
$dateTo = new DateTime();

$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openMemory();
$writer->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$writer->startElement('message');

    $writer->startElement('part');
        $writer->writeAttribute('name', 'studentId');
        $writer->writeAttribute('type', 'xsd:integer');
        $writer->Text();
    $writer->endElement($studentId);

    $writer->startElement('part');
        $writer->writeAttribute('name', 'type');
        $writer->writeAttribute('type', 'xsd:string');
        $writer->Text($type);
    $writer->endElement();

    $writer->startElement('part');
        $writer->writeAttribute('name', 'dateFrom');
        $writer->writeAttribute('type', 'xsd:date');
        $writer->Text($dateFrom->format('Y-m-d'));
    $writer->endElement();

    $writer->startElement('part');
        $writer->writeAttribute('name', 'dateTo');
        $writer->writeAttribute('type', 'xsd:date');
        $writer->Text($dateTo->format('Y-m-d'));
    $writer->endElement();

    $writer->startElement('part');
        $writer->writeAttribute('name', 'description');
        $writer->writeAttribute('type', 'xsd:string');
        $writer->Text($description);
    $writer->endElement();

    $writer->startElement('part');
        $writer->writeAttribute('name', 'extraField1');
        $writer->writeAttribute('type', 'xsd:string');
        $writer->Text($extraField1);
    $writer->endElement();

    $writer->startElement('part');
        $writer->writeAttribute('name', 'extraField2');
        $writer->writeAttribute('type', 'xsd:string');
        $writer->Text($extraField2);
    $writer->endElement();

    $writer->startElement('part');
        $writer->writeAttribute('name', 'extraField3');
        $writer->writeAttribute('type', 'xsd:string');
        $writer->Text($extraField3);
    $writer->endElement();

$writer->endElement(); // /message
$writer->endDocument();

$message = $writer->outputMemory(true);
```

Don't forget to set your values first.